# Can I enable a VS Code extension only for files with a specific extension / editors with a specific language mode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I'm an extension user (not an author). I would like to enable a VS Code extension only for certain file types.

Specifically, I'd like to enable spell check only in markdown files and other text documents.
Enabling spellcheck by workspace doesn't meet my intent. I often want spellcheck in workspaces that have both markdown and other code files.

**Potential lead**:
I know [languages activation events](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events) can be specified in an extension manifest. It doesn't appear that I can customize that manifest without creating a new plugin though.

Comment: Q: Do you mean that you have a project with 3 .md files, 10 .html files and 5 .cs files, but you only want your extension to process the .md and .html files?  Or do you mean something else entirely?

Comment: That is the right idea. I edited the question to hopefully be more clear

Comment: check the active editor and do the stuff when the language ID is correct

Comment: Yes, you can also do an activation event for the language - but once you visit that language file the extension remains activated no matter what other language file you open thereafter - a little odd behaviour in my opinion so you do have to always check the active editor languageID.

Comment: @rioV8 (and Mark) I'm unaware of how to check the active editor's languageID without making a custom extension. 
I do see there are [language specific settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_languagespecific-editor-settings), but enabling and disabling a plugin is not an available setting.

Answer (score 0):

On the user end, if the extension doesn't already register itself only for specific languages, and doesn't do anything else to scope its work to editors with specific [language modes](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers), and doesn't provide any settings to make it do that, then you're out of luck.

Since you mentioned spell-checking extensions, I know for a fact that [`streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker) has the [`cSpell.files`](https://streetsidesoftware.com/vscode-spell-checker/docs/configuration/#cspellfiles) setting that takes an array of glob pattern strings to enable checking for, accepting positive and negative (prefixed with `!`) patterns, and also the similar [`cSpell.enableFiletypes`](https://streetsidesoftware.com/vscode-spell-checker/docs/configuration/#cspellenablefiletypes), and the corresponding [`cSpell.checkOnlyEnabledFileTypes`](https://streetsidesoftware.com/vscode-spell-checker/docs/configuration/#cspellcheckonlyenabledfiletypes).