# Can I enable a VSCode extension on additional file extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can I enable a VSCode extension on additional file extensions?

Specifically, there is a plugin that works on .md files, that I would like to enable in .Rmd files.

Related to this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66701175/can-i-enable-a-vs-code-extension-only-for-files-with-a-specific-extension-edit) but in the opposite direction.

Comment: If you do Ctrl+Shift+P -> "change language mode", does your extension work? If yes, you can configure the default language for this extension in `settings.json`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat : yes, it does, if I change language mode to plain markdown inside an .Rmd file, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to `settings.json` to change the default language association for .Rmd files to "markdown":

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.Rmd": "markdown",
},
```